# Difference in continuing and episodic cases in Sutton and Barto - Introduction to RL, exercise 3.5

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, sutton-barto, markov-chain

> Excercise 3.5 The equastions in Section 3.1 are for the continuing
>   case and need to be modified (very slightly) to apply to episodic
>   tasks. Show that you know the modifications needed by giving the
>   modified version of (3.3).

$\displaystyle\sum_{s^{\prime} \in S} \displaystyle\sum_{r \in R} = p(s^{\prime}, r 
| s,a) = 1$ , for all $s\in S, a \in A(s)$    (3.3)

Is it just about final states? So for $s \in S$ when S is not final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it just about final states? So for $s \in S$ when S is not final?

You are thinking the right way, but to represent what you mean you don't need to write out "when $s$ is not final" - although that would be fine (and is used in some places), there is a more concise way of saying that given to you by the book.

As this is a formal exercise from the book, I don't want to write out an answer that could be cut&paste for all students.

Instead I suggest you take a look at the notations section at the beginning of the book, and find how Sutton & Barto use different set labels for all states including terminal states, and all states excluding terminal states. Also, check carefully which of those sets needs to be summed over.

Comment: Thank you! I guess you mean $S$ and $S^+$, so $s \in S$ already means it's not final. Still I'm not sure what's the difference between continuing and episodic cases in the context of this equation.

Comment: @JakubBielan: Look at the sums

Comment: I think I got it :) When I'll be able to give acknowledgement for your answer, I'll remember to do it for sure

Comment: @NeilSlater hey I wanted to clarify a doubt..I tagged you in the chat but probably you weren't notified...Can you check 'the singularity' and clarify my doubt?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself turning in cycles for a while, so to clarify Neil Slater's answer,

In the beginning of the book, $S$ means "set of non-terminal states" and $S^+$ means "set of all states, including the terminal ones".

$$\sum_{s^{\prime} \in S} \sum_{r \in R} p(s^{\prime}, r | s,a) = 1, \forall s \in S, a \in A(s) \tag{3.3}$$

That said, in eq. 3.3 when we define that $\forall s \in S$, we say that that once in a terminal state, the formula does not apply (which is obvious because no action is ever available in a terminal state by definition).

It does not however constraint the probability in how to "get" in a terminal state, and that is the key to answer the question.